# R hangs when trying to save as on mac running high sierra

Tags: r, macos

R is hanging and freezing when I try to save as, happens on scripts and graphics files. R is running:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30) -- "Kite-Eating Tree"
```

This error message happens every time I try to save as, aswell.

> objc[7900]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit
>   (0x7fffa33dfb68) and
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
>   (0x10993bcd8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Have tried to use things like running R from bash like suggested in other answers to R hanging but this doesn't help.

Comment: How are you trying to save? I can cause a similar error in Quartz by saving with `Cmd-S`, but using graphics devices like `png()` (which lets you control size, file format, etc., too) works fine.

Comment: What is your goal? What are you trying to "save"? What is your setup?

Comment: It's when I am trying to save script files, or when I am trying to save graphics files from quartz - when I save the graphics file as a pdf through code it works fine but when I use file - save as  it runs this error and hangs when I try to name the file. Ideally I'd like R to not freeze and need to restart R every time I try to save a script. What do you mean by set up, besides what I have specified in the question? Thanks